# C and fwrite stream != null

Tags: c

I have program that after he gets event of conected device he try to get data from it and save on hard drive, code to save:

```
        FILE *fp_binary = fopen(appdata, "wb"); 

        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer), fp_binary); 

        fclose (fp_binary);
```

So, when I run this program it works OK, but if I disconect device and conect it again:
[image]

appdata is path to appdata folder and name of file is always different
buffer is re-created

@Edit

At first run:
[image]
At second run:

[image]

Comment: You didn't check the result of `fp_binary = fopen(appdata, "wb");` to make sure the results aren't `NULL`. You really should before attempting to use `fp_binary`. If the results are `NULL`, that means it couldn't open the file `appdata` for writing.

Comment: After you assign `fp_binary = fopen(appdata, "wb");` you need to check if `fp_binary` is `NULL` using `if (fp_binary == NULL) { /* show an error message and recover here */ }`. If it is `NULL`, then you have an error: you were unable to open the file for writing. Your code will need to perform the proper recovery procedures in that case, perhaps just exit. And then you'll have to investigate why it couldn't open the file. Since you haven't shared the actual file and path name or other details about the file, I can't help you with that part.

Comment: Most functions you can call may fail under certain circumstances.  I/O functions especially fall in this category, and more than most other functions, their failures may not be predictable based on your program's code.  You should *always* test for errors, and *handle* such errors when they occur, even if only by displaying a diagnostic and exiting.  Do NOT use assertions for this purpose.  They are for testing conditions that you expect never to be false unless your program is broken.

Comment: OK i have added: if(fp_binary == NULL) and it returns true, so why this could happen?

Comment: @Carlos28: Look to what `errno` has been set (e.g. `perror(appdata);`).

Comment: OK the problem was not clearing properly file path....